# WordPress post image change on hover (ACF?)

Tags: wordpress, hover, advanced-custom-fields

On a WordPress page, I'm having the post image as a background-image in the header. Here's how it is solved:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>         

        <header class="header" role="banner" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">...</div>
```

What I want now is add a second image to the post (Advanced Custom Fields??) which should be displayed on hover. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Since not every header image has a second image for hover, I have created 2 custom fields called "normal" and "hover". If the post has a post image, it's a "static" header, if there is no post image, I'm getting "normal" and "hover". I creted a condition to distinguish those 2 types:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>
    <header class="header" role="banner" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"> 
<?php else : ?>
    <header class="header" role="banner" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('normal'); ?>');">   
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I need now is to get my second image, "hover" as a hover...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Advance custom field plugin to upload second image for post.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But where would I need to specify this image as a hover? Can I do it in PHP? My knowledge there is a little limited.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
    <?php $image = get_field('image'); 
          $imagehover = get_field('imagehover'); 
          ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>         

    <header class="header" role="banner" data-alt-src="<?php echo $hoverimage['url']; ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>')">
```

And use jquery on hover of image like this,

```
$(.header).hover(function(){
   var hoversrc = $(this).data('alt-src');
   $(this).css('background-image','url(' + hoversrc + ')');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting an error message: "background-image: url('<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'url' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wuest\wp-content\themes\wuest\header.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />
My line 44:   <header class="header" role="banner" data-alt-src="<?php echo $hoverimage['url']; ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>')">

Comment: In the_field(); function you will not get url of image please try as describe in my answer $imagehover = get_field('imagehover'); $imagehover['url'];

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If anyone is interested:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>        
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>
<style type="text/css"> 
     .header { 
         background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb[0]; ?>');
     } 
</style> 
<?php else : ?>
    <?php $image = get_field('normal');  ?> 
<?php $imagehover = get_field('hover');  ?> 
<style type="text/css"> 
     .header { 
         background-image: url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>'); 
     } 
     .header:hover {
         background-image: url('<?php echo $imagehover['url']; ?>'); 
     }
</style>
<?php endif; ?>

<header class="header">   ..</div>
```